# How can I set the margin parameters of a plot graphic to avoid labels being cut?

Tags: r, plot, margin, label, graphic

I'm plotting a series of data, using the following code:

```
x <- 2008:2016
y <- c(757221, 768845, 672496, 672387, 682506, 657828, 630625, 639334, 1178876)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(oma = c(2.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
plot(x, y, bty = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", pch = 18, col = "#5889C1", xaxp = c(2008, 2016, 8), cex = 1.5)
yl <- format(y, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
poslab <- c(1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3)
text(x, y, labels = yl, pos = poslab, cex = 0.9)
lines(x, y, col = "#5889C1", lwd = 3)
```

But some labels, in the borders of the screen are not entirely shown (unfortunately, I couldn’t upload an image, but will continue trying): anyone who rerun this code will see the first label cut at left, the seventh cut at bottom and the ninth (last) cut at top.

So, I wish to know how can I reset the margin parameters to avoid it and allow all labels to be entirely shown.

Comment: `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`   ?

Comment: Set the `x` and `y` limits. In your plot call, I'd add `ylim=range(y)*c(0.9,1.3), xlim=c(2007,2017)`.

Comment: Setting `par(xpd=NA)` might also help: see `?par` for the documentation.